# Why Websocket connection is disconneting after sending message on iOS 15 devices?

Tags: javascript, websocket, ios15

I am building a website based on web socket communication. Its is working fine until iOS 14 but started breaking from iOS 15. Web socket java script client is able to open connection to server, but upon trying to send a message, the connection is getting closed. Following is my html and JS code.

```
function start_websocket() {
  connection  = new WebSocket("wss://localhost/wss/");
  connection.onopen = function () {
    console.log('Connection Opened');        
  };
  connection.onerror = function (error) {
    console.log('WebSocket Error ' + error);
  };
  connection.onclose = function(){
    console.log("Closed");
  };
  connection.onmessage = function (e) {
    console.log("Message Received :" + e.data);
  };
 }

function myFunction() {
   var testText = document.getElementById("testText");
   if (testText.value != "" && connection.readyState === connection.OPEN) {
      connection.send("Test");
   }
}
start_websocket();
```

myFunction() is an on-click event of a button.

A Java Websocket server is used, which will decode and send the messages based on the Data framing in https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455#section-5.

Saw different articles on the Web, but didn't found a solution to this issue. Any suggestions are much appreciated. Looking forward for your answers

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using wss - secure websockets - on the localhost. Did you try without SSL? Just `connection  = new WebSocket("ws://localhost/wss/");` Maybe the browser gets irritated by not receiving the correct certificate (because you certainly do not have a valid certificate for localhost ...)

Comment: Thanks Nechoj for your comment. Yes I did try with ws. Here I am trying to replicate the same thing what I have on production server. We do have a valid ssl certificate on production server.

Comment: Have you tried running the server on port 443? Web sockets rely on an HTTP Upgrade to work properly. HTTP Upgrades are also used in HTTPS connections to "promote" a plaintext connection to an encrypted one. Some clients might find HTTP Upgrades on ports other than 443 to be suspicious and may block them.

Comment: Hello Badr B, Thanks for the comment. I also tried using port 443. The same thing is working w/o any issues on different browsers of android mobiles. The issue persists only on iOS 15 devices. When I debug the received messages on the server side, the messages are incomplete in the case of iOS 15 devices.

Comment: You did not mention what was the result when using `ws`. Does the error persist without SSL?

Comment: It is working on ws. But I don't think ws can be used on production server

Comment: I had issue with websocket not respecting compression setting, and dropping connections.  Only way I made it work was by disabling the newer websocket library in safari, and that was not a practical solution.

Comment: I agree Steven. I tried it as well. However, latency is increasing without compression. Also I tried disabling NSURLSession WebSocket in safari experimental features. This makes the application works in only safari, but not other browsers on the phone.